# PhpStorm: ignore runtime / logic exceptions

Tags: php, exception, phpstorm, phpdoc, docblocks

In `PhpStorm's` settings in `Editor/Inspections/PHP/PHPDoc/Missing @throw tag(s)` there are two options which are selected by default:

- Ignore Runtime Exceptions
- Ignore Logic Exceptions

[image: Missing throw tags]

**QUESTION**: Why would I want to ignore these specific exceptions while creating DocBlock? I guess this needs to have a solid reason since these options are checked by default.

`Logic Exceptions` are exceptions like `DomainException` or `InvalidArgumentException`.
`Runtime Exceptions` are exceptions like `RangeException` or `UnderflowException`

Note: I'm using PhpStorm v8.0.3

Comment: I think it's because these exceptions are normally thrown by PHP built-in functions, not explicitly by your code. Since they can be thrown by any function, it would be unreasonable for every function to document that it can throw them.

Comment: but is there something wrong in throwing for example ``InvalidArgumentException`` by myself? I do it quite often. I checked ``Symfony2`` code and they do it too

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. All this option does is tell PhpStorm not to warn about all the functions that don't have `@throws InvalidArgumentException` in their documentation.